# How to send certain data received by a request to a telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Please tell me, I receive the following data with a request:

```
 "cd": {
"pol": [
{
"bd": 111111,(value changes)
"cmn": {
"al": "32423434543534532",
"amd": "22222", (value changes)
"mtt": "BBB",
"pol": "0"
}
}
],
"snd":[{ (may be empty depending on the request)
"bd":23232,
"cmn":{
"al": "32423434543534532",
"amd": "32323", (value changes)
"mtt": "BBB",
"pol":"117780"
}
}]
```

They helped me with the code and send the necessary data to telegram:
import telebot

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR_TOKEN_BOTA') 
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def start_message(message): 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, hi!') 
     

def handle_data(data): 
    message = f'in "pol": "bd": {data["cd"]["pol"][0]["bd"]}, "amd": "{data["cd"]["pol"][0]["cmn"]["amd"]}"\n' 
    if data["cd"]["snd"]: 
        message += f'in "snd": "bd": {data["cd"]["snd"][0]["bd"]}, "amd": "{data["cd"]["snd"][0]["cmn"]["amd"]}"' 
    else: 
        message += ' "snd" no' 
         
    bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, message)


data = requests.get('YOUR REQUEST').json()
handle_data(data)
```

Everything works but how to send bd and amd from several blocks. Those. there can be more than one data in the pol and snd block. Example in pool 2 blocks in snd 1 block:

```
 "cd": {
"pol": [
{
"bd": 111111,(value changes)
"cmn": {
"al": "32423434543534532",
"amd": "22222", (value changes)
"mtt": "BBB",
"pol": "0"
}
},
{
"bd": 323232,(value changes)
"cmn": {
"al": " ",
"amd": "536", (value changes)
"bl": "fdgfdfdgdfgdfgdfgerer",
"pol": "0"
}
}
],
"snd":[{ (may be empty depending on the request)
"bd":23232,
"cmn":{
"al": "32423434543534532",
"amd": "32323", (value changes)
"mtt": "BBB",
"pol":"117780"
}
}
]
```

The result of a message for a telegram is to receive such a plan.
received data from "pol":
bd:111111
amd:22222
bd:323232
amd:536
sent data from "snd":
bd:23232
amd:32323

Looked for something similar and couldn't find it. I'm new